# Audition samples in Logic Pro

Tags: logic-pro

I have a folder with samples from a hardware sampler. Most of the samples are tuned to C. I have string samples and bell samples, for example.

I would like to use these in Logic Pro. So I have a MIDI melody but would like to very conveniently and quickly switch between the sample that is playing the melody, so I can figure out which sample works best.

How do I do this in Logic? I can’t establish if ESX24 is designed to work this way. There are a few hundred samples in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this would be to create ESX24 instruments for each of the sample sets you are looking to compare.

Then create a set of tracks with the esx24 midi instrument - one for each sample set instrument.

Duplicate the midi data across all the tracks and then solo the track for the instrument you are looking to audition.

Comment: The problem is that I have several hundred samples.

Comment: Then it will take a while. Best get started. There are some shortcuts to creating esx24 instruments that relate to the naming of the samples. Lots of youtube howto's out there that demonstrate this workflow.